# Remove warning "Option baseHref is deprecated, use baseHref option in the browser builder itself"

Tags: angular

I upgraded the Angular version of my project to version 11, and then I got an error while running: "`Option baseHref is deprecated, use baseHref option in the browser builder itself`".

I tried to put `baseHref: "/certs/"` in angular.json but still I'm getting the error.

Please help me to get rid out of this error.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @hbthanki Remove --base-href from package json and add it in Angular.json's "options": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "baseHref": "/MyApp",
              "deployUrl": "/MyApp"
}

Answer (score 5):

In `angular.json` it needs to go under the options for build-angular:browser. See the fragment below:

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
   "baseHref": "/ui/",
   "deployUrl": "/ui/"
```