# is there a way for ng build to put the generated chunk files into a subfolder?

Tags: angular

When I run ng build, the index.html file has all the chunk files loaded such as:

```
<script src="runtime.f18a52e6b282410f.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills.fd5c3a299b237232.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

Is there an option when building that will allow me to have all of files created put into a subfolder so that I will end up with an index.html file that will look something like like:

```
<script src="my-subfolder/runtime.f18a52e6b282410f.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="my-subfolder/polyfills.fd5c3a299b237232.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ng build' with all scripts in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794113/ng-build-with-all-scripts-in-subfolder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if that's what you want

```
ng build --output-path=dist/my_path_subfolder
```

it will put all the the generated files, including the index.html file and chunk files into the dist/my-subfolder directory.

EDIT:

currently i am unable to run this so i need you to run the build and verify the result with us

1st in side if your the angular.json file in the root directory of your angular project.

then you should see `architect` section and find the `build` configuration for your project and then within the `options` of the `build` configuration add the following properties as below

```
"baseHref": "/subfolder/",
"deployUrl": "/subfolder/"
```

also yo might want to go through [whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular)

Comment: Yeah, no that's not what I want.  That will not change the paths of the resources in the index.html file..  I want the index to be in the output-path folder, but the script tags, style tags, etc to reference things in a subfolder.

Comment: did you go through the edit part?

Comment: yeah, it looks like deployUrl did what I want, not baseHref.  However, it's deprecated.

Comment: see this might be helpful [go through this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23765) and [remove-warning-option-basehref-is-deprecated-use-basehref-option-in-the-browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453909/remove-warning-option-basehref-is-deprecated-use-basehref-option-in-the-browse)